# Handle pagination of Facebook friends using social framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, pagination

I can successfully fetch facebook friend list with following code:

```
- (void) myProfile{
    NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

     NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"birthday,email,first_name,gender,hometown,id,link,last_name,name,location,timezone,friends",@"fields", nil];

    SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                        URL:meurl
                                                 parameters:param];

    merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

    [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dictjson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
         NSLog(@"data:%@",dictjson);
        [self getPublicActionResponse:dictjson];
    }];
}
```

but I could not understand hot to handle paging of facebook friends with this code. In console I got key "paging" in response but I could not understand how to pass paging url and get all listed friends.